# Why react app jsconfig.json is not working with gitlab ci/cd pipeline with creat-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci, create-react-app, gitlab-ci-runner

I have added a pipeline for my `creat-react-app` project which a `jsconfig.json` for my alias defined.
Looks like.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",
            "es2016",
            "es6",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "actions": ["actions/*"],
            "assets": ["assets/*"],
            "components": ["components/*"],
            "containers": ["containers/*"],
            "constants": ["constants/*"],
            "config": ["config/*"],
            "helpers": ["helpers/*"],
            "stores": ["stores/*"],
            "styles": ["styles/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

Which works great with my vscode or webstorm.
But doesn't work for my pipeline,
`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - dependencies
  - build
  - deploy

dependencies:
  stage: dependencies
  cache: 
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - yarn config set ignore-engines true
    - yarn global add firebase-tools
    - yarn
  only:
    refs:
      - next-release
    changes:
      - package.json
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules

build:
  stage: build
  cache: 
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    policy: pull
  only:
    - next-release
  script:
    - yarn config set ignore-engines true
    - yarn build
    - yarn global add firebase-tools
    - firebase deploy --only functions,hosting -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID, build $CI_BUILD_ID" --non-interactive --token 1/x_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxtokenxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -P xxxxxxxxxx-appp
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build
```

It throws an error saying
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/Textarea' in '/builds/mac/app/src/containers/ComponentName'`

Any idea how to fix this? Or anyone has created a pipeline with alias with `create-react-app` with any ci-cd pipeline?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to override the webpack config of CRA. These might help:https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7205#issuecomment-507811588 and https://dev.to/heybrunoandrade/configuring-absolute-paths-in-react-for-web-without-ejecting-en-us-52h6

Answer (score 0):

According to Create React App documentation about [absolute imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports) you should be able to configure it in your `jsconfig.json` like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Have you tried adding the `"include": ["src"]`?

You don't need to explicitly specify the paths as long as each of your absolute folders are under `src`.

So your `jsconfig.json` becomes:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",
            "es2016",
            "es6",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",

    },
    "include": ["src"]
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```